# Translate camera to rotate left ('Q') and right ('E')

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I'm trying to translate the camera when I press Q and E I want for example when I press 'q' that the camera translate to the left and let me give a movement that is like a camera rotation, to do **that I tried this:**

```
public class cameraMove : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject player;       //Public variable to store a reference to the player game object
    private float moveSpeed;

    private Vector3 offset;         //Private variable to store the offset distance between the player and camera

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        //Calculate and store the offset value by getting the distance between the player's position and camera's position.
        offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
    }

    void Update(){


        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Q))
            transform.position += Vector3.up * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.E))
            transform.position += -Vector3.up * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;



    }

    // LateUpdate is called after Update each frame
    void LateUpdate () 
    {
        // Set the position of the camera's transform to be the same as the player's, but offset by the calculated offset distance.
        transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
    }
}
```

I already had the code living on LateUpdate, to follow the player, now I want to adapt the code so it does both, follow the player and translate the camera on the button clicks, when I press the keys in this case nothing happen, i feel that is because the late update transform, but I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment in your code, `LateUpdate` is called after `Update` and is resetting your camera's position.

Comment: yeah i know that it is a problem, how can i do to solve that, so i can do the 2 things

Comment: How about simply change `offset` instead of `transform.position` in the `Update` function ?

Comment: You can move all the code to just one of these methods. For example, in my Unity program all the camera control stuff happens in `LateUpdate` and there is no `Update` method.

Comment: did what you guys sugested, but still nothing happens related to the camera translate

Comment: actually i did it, but the camera now go up and down

Comment: just want to kinda orbit around the player

Answer (score 0):

If you want the camera to orbit around the player(as stated in your comment), in your `cameraMove`'s script `Update()` method:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
{
  transform.RotateAround(player.transform.position, player.transform.up, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
{
  transform.RotateAround(player.transform.position, player.transform.up, -moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```